# Is it possible to create a modal dialog similar to the Intellisense dialog in a Visual Studio extension?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to figure out if and how I can create a custom dialog in a Visual Studio extension similar to the Intellisense dialog:

[image: Intellisense dialog]

and the Find & Replace dialog.

[image]

I don't want to create an entirely new WPF window that is separated from visual studio (i.e. has its own icon on the start bar) - I want a dialog that is within VS that can supports custom controls. I specifically want a dialog like this that has a ListView and a TextBox.

Is that at all possible? I've searched around a lot but resources seem scarce. Is there at least a way to fake this behaviour?

Comment: There are quite a few extensibility samples here - https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples; do any approximate what you're looking for?

Comment: @KimJohnson unfortunately not :-(

Comment: By the way, you should learn the difference between modal and modeless dialog...

Comment: You might have an idea of what is possible by trying some extensions and see what they do.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm not understanding what you're asking for Jack. What are you trying to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it's 2018 now, but if anyone come across this page in a search and wants to know the answer to the same question, I've added a link to the official Microsoft documentation.

Have a look at [Adding a Tool Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-tool-window) which shows the various ways to add a WPF `ToolWindow` control to Visual Studio.